# Why am I unable to continue reviewing first posts after reaching the vote limit?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, voting, review

I was surprised to see this while reviewing first posts:
[image: Screenshot: Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in 14 hours.]

Since voting is not the only thing to do when reviewing, and arguably not the most useful (I find editing/close votes/comments to be a better tool personally), it seems weird that I'm unable to continue after reaching the daily vote limit. Is this a bug, or is it made so by-design?

Comment: If they made a specific message for that event, I think it's safe to say that it's by design :)

Comment: @Lix, but if I'd just stopped with 39 votes, I could continue reviewing forever ;) I think such behavior is... strange

Comment: I think the issue is you are limited to only a few things - share|edit|close|flag ... What happens if the first time post is perfect and doesn't need editing - the only thing you can do to mark it 'this is fine' is to upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely by-design.

The following tools are available to you when reviewing first posts from the review queue:

1. Voting up/down
2. Editing
3. Voting to close (on questions) or delete (on negatively-scored answers)
4. Flagging
5. Commenting

*All* of these except for editing are rate-limited in some way. And of the five, voting and editing are the two most important - not only are they critical to the overall quality of the site, but specifically in the case of new users, they are our primary means of welcoming new users and demonstrating our commitment to high-quality questions and answers.

So if you can't vote, you're left with editing as your primary tool in this queue. While I'd love to think this was enough, in practice folks vote a *lot* more than they edit - even on Stack Overflow, there are only 2 people *consistently* averaging more than 30 edits a day. Editing takes more time and effort than any other action on that list, hence the lack of external rate-limiting. If you're diligently editing all or most of the posts you review, more power to you - and if you're done for the day in the First Posts queue, you might find your skills put to good use by either the Low Quality or Suggested Edits queues.

> I find editing/close votes/comments to be a better tool personally

Close votes are also rate-limited, can only be used on questions, and even then only used on a minority of questions. If you have close votes to burn, [there's a whole queue waiting for you](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close)... Comments are nice, but also the most toothless of the bunch - and they also suffer from the same problem as editing: leaving *good* comments takes more time than anything else. If those were the only tools available to you, it would be a pretty useless queue.

**Voting is the easiest, fastest, and IMHO most useful thing you can do in the First Posts queue** - if you do nothing else, please vote. And if you burn through all of your votes reviewing first posts, consider that the sign of a job well done. *Thank you*!

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer :P

Comment: I just ran into this the first time - while I do understand *why* you chose this, I still think it's kind of ridiculous that you lose the ability to see reviews at 40 votes, but can see all the reviews you like if you just stay at 39 votes and never use your last one... (Mostly what I use the review for is finding more items that need flagging ;))

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.  Perhaps this is because they moves the "First Posts" lists in to the new review tools.

In the meantime, while we wait for an answer here from one of the SE team, you can carry on your reviewing from the old lists -

- [First Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day)
- [First Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day)

Just click on ["late answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) from the [beta review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), and you'll see all the tabs for the old lists.

[image]