# Why am I required to do something to first time posts?

Tags: discussion, review

What is required from me in reviewing a post? There is a similar question on [Stack Overflow Meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147052/unable-to-continue-reviewing-after-using-the-vote-limit#comment421883_147052)

I clicked on [review](https://meta.superuser.com/review/) and see many first time posts. I see I have 2 options:

- I'm done
- Not sure.

I'm done is grayed out. I don't understand why as this actually now forces the post to be edited or voted up when in many cases neither of these are applicable.

So, I guess by voting up is a good way to start - it rewards new posters for good questions and makes them feel welcome - and what happens -- I'm limited to X number of votes a day (up voting and down voting). Currently there are 2.1k posts on Super User which need reviewing and with these limitations I expect it will take some time (although I use Super User, it's applicable to all sites on SE).

I don't think writing a comment saying 'well done for a good post' is useful either for future visitors (IMO it also may impact SEO but we won't discuss that here) but it adds 'noise'.

Any thoughts on this, have I missed the point?

Comment: You are not required to do anything to anything.  There are thousands of first time posts to which I have done absolutely nothing - not even read their titles.

Comment: @PaulButcher - thank you. This is what I was expecting but it seems SE would allow them to remain 'lost' - why have this feature if it doesn't matter if the posts are or are not reviewed!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rationale is that if you're not sure on what to do from the options given, just click "not sure". This will keep the post in the queue until someone finds something to do with it.

Read more on [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146991/159624).

> The biggest issue with the old review system was apathy - providing a "Meh" button for folks who don't want to make a call doesn't really do anything but create busywork for folks who want to feel like they're participating without actually doing anything — [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts?lq=1#comment421786_146991)

This is, in my personal opinion, ridiculous since there are enough posts that really don't *need* to be voted on, are already edited, don't need to be closed and surely don't need to be flagged either. By saying that this post is fine as is, you're also making a decision. We have the "Looks Good" button on other review queues too.

> I think that having the "I am done" button enabled from the beginning is like having the "Looks Good" button enabled in the low quality queue — [kiamlaluno](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146991/159624)

I think it comes down to voting — the assumption being made that you should vote on every post. Otherwise you won't get out of this anyway.

Jonsca has summed up the issue pretty well:

> There are only two possible actions in this new queue: something and nothing. That's forcing me to upvote something that may not deserve it or pass the responsibility to someone else, otherwise these new posts will just fester in the queue while we all play "not sure" volleyball with them — [jonsca](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts?lq=1#comment421772_146991)

The idea of getting rid of this requirement seems very popular from the community's point of view but the site owners would like to enforce this way of reviewing, at least until first statistics are there.

Until then, click "not sure" when you're sure there's nothing to be done with the post. Yes, it seems awkward to do, but that's what you can do for the moment.

Comment: OK - this answers it although the issue clearly remains 'unresolved' until the boys at the top can decide what is the best for everyone! Thank you.

Comment: You might just want to wait until they've decided to keep it, or vote the hell out of kiamlaluno's post.